# Requisição de URL em Swift

Tags: swift, url, request

Como que eu faço para puxar somente o nome e o pôster dessa página  : https://www.themoviedb.org/search/remote/multi?query=exterminador%20do%20futuro&language=en

Para um projeto em Swift ?

Comment: Você quer um JSON que retorne apenas o Nome e Pôster ou quer saber como extrair esses dados do JSON pro seu projeto?

Comment: Acho que os dois. 

Pq é o seguinte... eu usei ali no exemplo o filme "exterminador do futuro" mas no projeto o usuário é que vai fazer a busca. Pode pesquisar por qualquer filme.

- então o link: https://www.themoviedb.org/search/remote/multi?query=
é padrão fixo. 
- Só que o usuário vai digitar o nome do filme. 
- Se no nome tiver espaço substitui por "%20"
e o final ali "&language=en" é fixo tbm.

- Quando faz a busca por qualquer filme, eu quero que o projeto mostre o nome e o pôster somente.
- Como faz isso em Swift ???

Comment: Eu encontrei um post seu alguns dias atrás perguntando como você poderia fazer o projeto. Antes de mais nada eu preciso saber o quanto você conhece de iOS. Já viu os tipos de navegações, tabelas, delegates, etc.. ? Se sim, ok vamos para o primeiro passo. 

Alamorife - https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Com ele você vai fazer sua requisição e ter o seu JSON, dê uma olhada na documentação.

Segundo passo é usar o Haneke - https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift

Você vai usar este para mostrar os posters

Comment: Não sei se você tem conhecimentos em programação, mas seria muito bom dar uma olhada em MVC para que você consiga estrurar seu projeto para que futuras atualizações e correções sejam mais fáceis de serem realizadas.

Também sugiro que veja os vídeos de Stanford - https://itunes.apple.com/br/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099 e da PUCRS - https://itunes.apple.com/br/course/desenvolvimento-ios-em-swift/id937721240

Vai te ajudar muito a começar a desenvolver apps iOS

Comment: Eu conheço pouco sobre iOS. Mas no momento eu tenho pouco tempo para estudar mais a fundo. Teria que fazer esse aplicativo que o usuário busca o nome e poster e o app mostra. Assim como ocorre no próprio site moviedb. É basicamente isso.

Se for possível vc poderia detalhar melhor como funciona esse Alamofire e o Haneke ??